# C pointer to function with unspecifiable signature

Tags: function-pointers, function-prototypes, ansi-c

I intend to explain a standard proof of recursion theorem in C, by using factorial as an example. So I have

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned Nat;
typedef Nat Func();

Nat G(Nat n, Func f){
    if(n) return n * f(n-1, f);
    else return 1;
}

int main(void){
    printf("%u", G(5, G));
    return 0;
}
```

It works (prints 120) on every compiler I could find, but what bothers me is that I'm passing a pointer to a function into a parameter that doesn't really have a fully specified type (it is a function returning Nat, but the parameter types aren't specified). Is it ok by the standard (any standard, but preferably the one that doesn't deprecate unspecified parameter types, so I guess C89:)?

Of course, I'd like even more to be able to fully specify Func, but it seems impossible (obvious way,

```
typedef Nat Func(Nat, Func);
```

doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

It's not as pretty, but you can have a fully specified type if you wrap it in a struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned Nat;
typedef struct wrapped_Func Func;
struct wrapped_Func {
  Nat (*call)(Nat, Func);
};
#define FUNC(f) ((struct wrapped_Func){.call=f})

static Nat G(Nat n, Func f){
    if(n) return n * f.call(n-1, f);
    else return 1;
}

int main(void){
    printf("%u\n", G(5, FUNC(G)));
    return 0;
}
```

(The struct literal in the `FUNC` macro is a C99 feature. in C89 it'll be even uglier.)

Comment: Yeah, and I can do whatever I want if I "wrap" it in a `void*`. :-) Don't get me wrong, your solution is awe-inducing, but I'd really like to pass G itself as an argument to G (since it is the main idea:), not some preprocessed version of it.